# Use reflection to load and instantiate module from package?

Tags: python

I have a package (a folder) named `models` containing
`__init__.py`, `model_a.py`, `model_b.py`.

my `__init__.py` contains:

```
from models.model_a import ModelA
from models.model_b import ModelB
```

In my `main.py` I do

```
import models

model = get_model(config.use_model) #config.use_model == "ModelA"

def get_model(model):
    # This should be equivalent to models.ModelA(**config.ModelA.structure)
    return models[model](**config[model].structure)
```

Which throws the error `TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable`

Basically what I want to do is elegantly load the model which is set in the config. Accessing the config like this works fine.

Comment: I dont think you can that.. if you still want to go ahead with this approach then you can just declare your own dict `models_d = {'ModuleA': models.ModuleA, 'ModuleB': models.ModuleB}`

Comment: @HamzaHaider is there another elegant way to return a class based on a string?

Comment: if you import `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` like the following `from models import ModuleA, ModuleB` then you can just use `eval('ModuleA')(..)` Although both examples arent really elegant

Comment: What exactly is `config`?

Comment: @martineau it is a parsed json config (Munch object). The properties can be accessed with either square brackets or dot notation.

Comment: In that case, if you want a definite answer, I think you need to remove usage of from your code and change what's left so it provides an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do programmatic attribute access, so you need to use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
return getattr(models, model)(**config[model].structure)
```

Subscripting (with square brackets, like `foo[1]`) is not the same as attribute access (with a dot, like `foo.bar`), in exactly the same way that `foo[2]` means something different to `foo(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know is it write but you can try this,

```
import models
import sys

def get_model(model):
    return getattr(models, model)


model = get_model('ModelA')
print(model())
```